# How to encapsulate behaviors in attribute to allow injecting code in the begin and end of each method decorated with it

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, decorator, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have C# class libraries and I want to put some logging for performance check for example:

```
protected void test()
{
    MyLogger.Info(String.Format("{0}|{1}", "..", "..."));
    ....
    MyLogger.Info(String.Format("{0}|{1}", "..", "..."));
}
```

I have a problem that I should put this two lines inside about 1300 methods in different classes in different layers so it will be a dummy work so i thought about injecting the code in the run-time in each method using AOP (PostSharp) or JIT Helper tools also i thought about code generator tool like that used in dependency injection but all of this may not meet my project needs.

I think about encapsulating the behavior in an attribute like that [LogPerformance] and then decorate all my needed methods with this attribute like that:

```
[LogPerformance]
protected void test()
{
    ....
}
```

And this attribute will inject the logging in the beginning and end of each method that tagged with it.

I know its easy to do so in MVC filters but i am now working on the business logic layers (Class library) so is it a way to allow me do that?

Also the way of creating attributes in .NET by inherit from Attribute class is mostly used to add metadata compiled into your program. Attributes themselves doesn't add any functionality to a class, property or module, just data. so is a way to allow me using it like the filters in ASP.NET MVC to add behaviors not only metadata?

Comment: Can you specify why PostSharp won't suit your needs? Seems like a by-the-book case for using it.

Comment: I am working on legacy code with .NET 3.5 framework and i don't think PostSharp will work with this code without any issue.